# Router access for virtualbox vm on internal network

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machine, bridge

I have two virtual box VMs. U1 and U2

VM **U1** has two adapters, enp0s3 which is bridged to my wireless adapter on my host machine and enp0s8 which is connected to internal network named "inet". Additionally I am also running a dhcp server on enp0s8 interface. I also configure static ip address for U1's enp0s8 interface using /etc/network/interfaces file

VM **U2** has one adapter, enp0s3 which is connected to internal network named "inet".

Now when I spin up U1 and then U2 and do

`ping <u1_enp0s8_ip_address>` from U2 I get a reply back

However when I try

`ping <u1_enp0s3_ip_address>` from U2, there is no response

Also I have tried

`ping -I enp0s8 <u1_enp0s3_ip_address>` in U1, and there is no response.

What do I need to do so that enp0s8 on U1 can communicate with enp0s3 on U1?

Any suggestions/replies will be highly appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now.

(EDIT 1)

Output from `sudo iptables -L` command

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

(EDIT 2)

`sudo iptables -L` command output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

(Edit 3)

Output from `route -n` command

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s8
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
```

enp0s3's (external network interface) network is 192.168.0.0/24 and enp0s8's (internal network interface) network is 10.0.1.0/24

Output from `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` command

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Regards

Comment: The answer from @kubanczyk is a good start - what OS are each VM running?

Comment: @ivanivan I am using ubuntu 16.04 on both

Answer (score 2):

On U1 you'll need to either set up NAT for the internal only network or open it up and just forward packets.  If you choose the second, you'll need to set appropriate routes on whatever machines on your physical LAN you want to connect to the virtual LAN.

If you want to set up NAT, you have to enable packet forwarding and set up some `iptables` rules.  Here's a script I use that does this -

```
#!/bin/bash
# a very simple set of iptables commands 
# to allow forwarding between ethernet
# devices


# which device is the one that connects to The World (or at least your
# non virtual LAN - this would be a Bridged or NAT (not NAT Network) type
# in VirtualBox
WAN_DEVICE="enp0s3"

# which device is the one that connects to Internal Only or Host Only network?
LAN_DEVICE="enp0s8"


# enable forwarding
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# where is iptables located?
iptables=`which iptables`

# flush all existing rules
$iptables -F

# this is for NAT
# enable masquerading
$iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN_DEVICE -j MASQUERADE

# don't forward packets from off-lan to lan if
# they are a brand new connection being formed
$iptables -A FORWARD -i $WAN_DEVICE -o $LAN_DEVICE -m state --state NEW -j REJECT

# if the packets come from off-lan but they are
# related to a connection that was established from
# within the lan, go ahead and forward them
$iptables -A FORWARD -i $WAN_DEVICE -o $LAN_DEVICE -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# whatever traffic comes from the lan to go to
# the world allow thru
$iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN_DEVICE -o $WAN_DEVICE -j ACCEPT
```

After running this, your iptables should look like

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

To just open it up, it is a bit overkill but you can simply change the rules above to accept all connections and forward in/out on both interfaces.  Doing this, you would also remove the NAT/Masquerade command, BUT you'd need to set routes on any machine that you wanted to connect from the physical LAN to the virutal.  Simply comment out the other `$iptables` calls (except the flush one) and duplicate the last line with the device references reversed, which reduces the script to -

```
#!/bin/bash
# a very simple set of iptables commands 
# to allow forwarding between ethernet
# devices


# which device is the one that connects to The World (or at least your
# non virtual LAN - this would be a Bridged or NAT (not NAT Network) type
# in VirtualBox
WAN_DEVICE="enp0s3"

# which device is the one that connects to Internal Only network?
LAN_DEVICE="enp0s8"


# enable forwarding
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# where is iptables located?
iptables=`which iptables`

# flush all existing rules
$iptables -F

# whatever traffic comes from the lan to go to
# the world allow thru
$iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN_DEVICE -o $WAN_DEVICE -j ACCEPT

# whatever traffic comes from the world to go to
# the lan allow thru
$iptables -A FORWARD -i $WAN_DEVICE -o $LAN_DEVICE -j ACCEPT
```

After you use this one, your iptables should look like

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Ran the script as it is. and then tried pinging my wan interface ip via internal interface ip but no luck :(

Comment: Can bridging help here. Can we somehow bridge the two interfaces on U1? I went that route yesterday and spent quite a bit of time but didn't get much luck. Perhaps I missed something. What do you think?

Comment: @AbdulRahman Your `enp0s3` adapter should be Bridged or NAT (but not NAT Network) in virtualbox.  Be sure it has an ip, etc.  What is output of `sudo iptables -L` ?

Comment: @ ivanivan my `enp0s3` is bridged and has an ip address. Also edited my question with the `sudo iptables -L` output

Comment: @AbdulRahman i added example `iptables -L` output from a working setup.  It looks like on yours you want traffic to flow both ways, but you left some of the other commands active.  Try running JUST the second script - should fix things up.  Don't forget to add appropriate routes.

Comment: edited my question with sudo iptables -L output. Matches your output but still no luck. What do you mean by "add appropriate routes" ? What routes should I add? Is there anything on top of running your script that I should be doing now?

Comment: @ ivanivan please also see edits for my question with the `route -n` command output. Looks like the rules I have should be good, unless I am missing something. Also with these rules and ip forwarding enabled and ip table rules shouldn't this shit just work now? :(

Answer (score 1):

Enable forwarding on U1. Most OSes by default don't do interface-to-interface routing unless you explicitly tell them.

Review the OS-level firewall rules on U1. Don't forget `nat` table too.

Comment: I followed this tutorial
http://opensourceforu.com/2015/04/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-a-router/ to configure forwarding rules and enabled ip forwarding but no luck still. Also I am using ubuntu